# does only throw statement in catch make any sense?

Tags: c#, exception

If I have a exception code like

```
 catch
 {
      throw;

 }
```

Does it make any sense? If suppose I dont write this code in function will the exceptions be treated similar in function or there is any difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, doesn't make sense as it is not handling the exception, but is just re-throwing

Answer (score 4):

The code itself does nothing, but that doesn't mean it's worthless. Think of it as a stub.

I have let code like this go into production, and every time what it means is that I had trouble there at some point, and during development I had additional code that I used for debugging that was later removed... something like an extra log message, MessageBox, or trace call, or even just a no-op kind of line (`string s = "";`) where I could put a break point. If you go look back in source control you'll be able to see those statements.

I like to leave the stub behind as a reminder that this section might be more difficult than it appears.

Looking at any random bit of code, though, a lot of the time this code exists because someone who didn't know any better just thought there should be a try/catch block there.

Comment: it helps in debugging you mean.

Answer (score 0):

No. It really doesn't make any sense by itself.

Without adding some sort of logging or other logic, this would be equivalent to not using a try/catch block at all.

Answer (score 0):

This is redundant.  It will catch any exception and then just rethrow it.  You're better off not using the `catch` at all, the results are the same and the code is less cluttered.

Answer (score 0):

in that situation the throw is in fact a re-throw and completely pointless if you have no other error handling.